# According to the Chicago manual of style for bibliographies do authors with initials have two stops before the title

Tags: style-manuals, cmos

According to the Chicago manual of style for bibliographies do authors with initials have two stops before the title?

So e.g.

Wells, H. G.. *The Invisible Man*

Comment: Might be worth looking at [academia SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com). I’m not sure bibliography style is considered on topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, only a single period.

*The Chicago Manual of Style* (17th ed.), 6.123 says this:

> When an abbreviation or other expression that ends with a period occurs at the end a sentence, no additional period follows . . . Of course, when any other mark of punctuation is needed immediately after the period, both the period and the additional mark appear.
>
> The study was funded by Mulvehill & Co.
> Johnson et al., in *How to Survive*, describe such an ordeal.

So, you never end up in a situation where there are two periods in a row. Depending on how you look at it, either the single period does "double duty" for the word or letter it terminates as well as the termination of the sentence or the terminal period is omitted.

In addition, *Chicago* offers some examples of bibliographical entries in Figure 14.8:

> Albury, W. R. “Politics and Rhetoric in the Sociobiology Debate.” *Social Studies of Science 10* (1980): 519–36.
> *Alien 3*. Directed by David Fincher. Los Angeles: Twentieth Century Fox, 1992.
> Allen, Garland E. “The Historical Development of the ‘Time Law of Intersexuality’ and Its Philosophical Implications.” In *Richard Goldschmidt: Controversial Geneticist and Creative Biologist: A Critical Review of His Contributions*, edited by Leonie K. Piternick, 41–48. Boston: Birkhauser, 1980.
> Angier, Natalie. “For Motherly X Chromosome, Gender Is Only the Beginning.” *New York Times*, 1 May 2007, 1.